# JavaScript Objects Target the value by the name of the key

Tags: javascript

```
const data = { bmw: { price: 200 } }

let carName = Object.keys(data).toString() 

console.log(carName)
// Output: bmw

let price = data.carName.price

console.log(price)
// Output: TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined

let price2 = data.bmw.price

console.log(price2)
// Output: 200
```

why I Can not use the name of the variable to access the price why i do have to type it by myself

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use:

```js
let price = data[carName].price

console.log(price)
```

This is because the carName property does not exist on data object, but the key with the value of the carName variable exists on the data object, so you need to use square brackets to get the price of the car